# New custom columns are not in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, column, ms-project

I have imported a MS-Project 2013 into our SharePoint 2013 and during the process I have mapped custom MS-Project columns, which now are part of my task list view.

What I'm trying to achieve here is to change the field type from single line to multi line, but I can't find the columns. The new columns are not shown on where the rest of the SharePoint site columns are. Any guidance will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

There are three places where columns can be defined: list/library, site (SPWeb) and site collection (SPSite).

Check all three and you will find them, in your case you're probably looking from too high level, e.g., looking at site collection level, when columns are in fact only created to specific site (SPWeb).